# Update A column based on values in B column

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

Let's say I have `Table1`, and `Table2` like below:

Table1

```
Nmae  ColA ColB
---------------
Peter 25   
Jason 52   
Tom   74
Jim   65
```

Table2

```
Values Prize
-------------
25     ABC
50     ABC1
75     ABC2
100    ABC3
```

Now I want to update `ColB` in `Table1` based on the values in `ColA`. 
e.g. If `value >= 25 and < 50` then `ABC`. If `value >= 50 and < 75` then `ABC1`.

Desired output:

```
Name ColA ColB
----------------
Peter 25   ABC
Jason 52   ABC1
Tom   76   ABC2
Jim   65   ABC1
```

I've tried to solve the problem by joining two tables to update ColB but got stuck. I know this can be easily done by using CASE WHEN. However, I'm worried that going forward if the rules change or what, I have to modify the code in multiple SPs.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off creating a view on the table which includes the calculation for ColB? That way if the rules change you only need to change it in one place as opposed to updating all your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that UPDATE using a subquery instead of a CASE WHEN

```
update table1 set ColB = (select top 1 Prize 
                          from table2 
                          where Values <= ColA order by Values desc)
```

Comment: Marc thanks for replying, but can you provide an answer by using join? since subquery could possibly lower the performance.

Comment: @AaronKuo Join, sub-query, performance will be just as good. SQL Server knows its stuff, don't try and second guess it.

Comment: @AaronKuo If you add an index on Table2 for the column Values, descending, the performance should be fine.